# Object data with 2 different types

Tags: java, android

I have the following:

```
public class Notifier{
    CustomPlayer mCustomPlayer;
    CurrentPlayer mCurrentPlayer;
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(){
        Notifier ntf = new Notifier();
        if( index == 0){
            ntf.mCustomPlayer = new CustomPlayer(this);
        }
        else{
            ntf.mCustomPlayer = new CurrentPlayer(this); // having problem here
        }
    }
}
```

In Notifier class, I just want to have one object mCustomPlayer to switch between CustomPlayer and CurrentPlayer in MainActivity class.

I tried adding the following in Notifier class,

```
public class Notifier{
    CustomPlayer mCustomPlayer;
    CurrentPlayer mCurrentPlayer;

    public Object getType(int index) {
        if (index == 1) {
            return CurrentPlayer.class;
        }
        else {
            return CustomPlayer.class;
        }
    }
}
```

With that I am having a problem when trying to initialize mCustomPlayer in MainActivity class.

```
ntf.mCustomPlayer = new (ntf.mCustomPlayer)getType(0); // compile error
```

Is there a way to realize this?
It has been a day since I am trying to configure out the correct implementation.
Should I use Interface in this case?

Comment: Can you add the errormessage please?

Comment: "CurrentPlayer and CustomPlayer has the same methods but differ in their functionality." Yes, this is precisely what interfaces are for. Abstract their methods into an interface instead.

Comment: @JakeKing I made a mistake in my question. Actually CurrentPlayer and CustomPlayer has different methods, that make things more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `new` keyword you *must* supply a class (i.e. `new MyClass()`).

You *could* use reflection for this... but wouldn't it be much simpler to just have a common superclass (or interface) for `CustomPlayer` and `CurrentPlayer`?

For example, suppose both `CustomPlayer` and `CurrentPlayer` have the `playOne()` and `playTwo()` methods. You could then define:

```
public interface Player {
    void playOne();
    void playTwo();
}

public class CurrentPlayer implements Player {
    @Override
    public void playOne() { 
        // code
    }

    @Override
    public void playTwo() {
        // code
    }
}

private class CustomPlayer implements Player {
    @Override
    public void playOne() {
        // code
    }

    @Override
    public void playTwo() {
        // code
    }
}

public class Notifier {
    Player mPlayer;
 }
```

And then assign `mPlayer` with `new CurrentPlayer()` or new `CustomPlayer()` You can then call any methods on the interface.

Comment: How to realize this if CurrentPlayer and CustomPlayer have different methods? I made a mistake in my question.

Comment: @LazyNinja First of all, not _all_ methods have to match, of course, only the ones you need to call from elsewhere; having other methods is ok. However, you state that you want to have _only one member_ and switch between these implementations -- that implies that they have at least a _minimum common interface_, otherwise that wouldn't make much sense to want to treat them interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the idea. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could using Reflection:

```
public class Notifier{

    public CommonInterface getInstance(int index, Class<Activity> activity){
      Class<?> claz = getType(0);
      Constructor<?> cons = claz.getConstructor(activity);
      return (CommonInterface) cons.newInstance(this);
      //or you could just type cast it manually if you do not wish to use CommonInterface
}
```

But having a common interface is the right way to go. You dont have to worry about reflection then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have same function for both the classes so use interface and access the object -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    interface CurrentPlayer  { void game(); }
    interface CustomPlayer   { void game(); }

    interface Player extends CurrentPlayer, CustomPlayer { }

     public void onCreate(){
        Player swan = new Player() {
            @Override 
            public void game() {
                System.out.println("Swan Player");  //Swan Player
            }
        };
     }
}
```